# Create an automatically command for: $\Rightarrow$

Tags: math-mode, macros

Is it possible to create a quick command for `$\Rightarrow$`, because when I write a math paper I use often this:  `$\Rightarrow$`. I know that the simple command `\Rightarrow` it can be shortcuted, but `$\Rightarrow$` can be shortcuted?

Thanks

Comment: You mean `\implies`?

Comment: \documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\Raw}{\ensuremath{\Rightarrow}}
\begin{document}
\Raw\ and $\Raw$
\end{document}

Comment: @HenriMenke: I think, the O.P. means a shortcut, that works always, in mathmode and in textmode

Comment: We have `\newcommand{\follows}{$\Rightarrow$}` in our framework. Simple and stupid ...

Comment: @user1129682 -- including the `$` signs around the command for the symbol will guarantee that it never has the correct spacing relative to what's around it.

Comment: I think that this is a matter of your editor. In my `vim` setup, I have `abbrev -> \Rightarrow` and this does it; typing `->` will give me a `\Rightarrow` immediately. They are even less keystrokes, and the final text is more readable by other people...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `\ensuremath` that switches to math-mode if needed and otherwise it's in math-mode already.

In general, markup is strongly suggested, but the question is, whether it's useful in any case, especially for a single symbol in any case.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\Raw}{\ensuremath{\Rightarrow}}%
\begin{document}
\Raw\ and $\Raw$

\Raw and $\Raw$

\begin{align}
  \Raw &\neq (\Raw)^2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The `\` at the end of `\Raw` is necessary in text-mode (it could be cured with `\xspace`, but I don't want to cause troubles ;-)

[image]

Comment: Do you need a `\\ after using `\Rightarrow`?

Comment: @Matsmath: Use it without and you see `→and`, i.e. theyaresticking;-)

Comment: I think `\To` would be a shorter (for sure!) and better name, since  `\to` already exists as a short cut for  `\rightarrow`.

Comment: `\To` is a little bit more error-prone. Typing `\to` when you mean `\To` can be quite tedious in 'debugging'